# How to update JSONB array in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table with following definition:

```
create table json_test (
    my_data jsonb);
```

Inserted to it values like this:

```
{"details": [
    {
        "f1": "",
        "f2": "free text"
    },
    {
        "f1": "",
        "f2": "free text"
    }
]}
```

Now I want to update this **jsonb column(f1 to null)**:

```
{"details": [
    {
        "f1": null,
        "f2": "free text"
    },
    {
        "f1": null,
        "f2": "free text"
    }
]}
```

I want to change the `f1` from string to null.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

On 9.3 you will have to rewrite your `jsonb` value.  From 9.5 you could use [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to simplify the task.